# How to override suhosin max value?

Tags: php, suhosin

An important GET param is being filtered by suhosin.
How do I override suhosin when the following does not work?

**public_html/php.ini :**

```
[suhosin]
suhosin.get.max_value_length = 2048
```

Sets suhosin.get.max_value_length among others to NULL and crashes user session.

-

**public_html/.htaccess :**

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value suhosin.get.max_value_length 2048
</IfModule>
```

No effect

-

(System default is set to:)

```
suhosin.get.max_value_length = 512
suhosin.get.max_value_length = 100000
```

The GET parameter being filtered is 576 chars long.

Comment: are you sure php.ini belongs in `public_html`? How are you serving PHP if mod_php5 isn't present?

Comment: Im not sure local php.ini override files are allowed at all. It does have effect though since 512 turns to NULL.

Comment: can you edit the global `php.ini`? Tried using `ini_get` / `ini_set` ?

Comment: ini_set isn't gonna help since these values needs to be set before the script executes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can bypass suhosin by re-building the $_GET

```
// Override suhosin $_GET limitation
  $_GET = array();
  $params = explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
  foreach ($params as $pair) {
    list($key, $value) = explode('=', $pair);
    $_GET[urldecode($key)] = urldecode($value);
  }
```

Comment: This just saved my bacon big time buddy, u rock!!

Answer (score 1):

On Debian|Ubuntu systems you can set the `suhosin` parameters globally in:

```
/etc/php5/conf.d/suhosin.ini
```

Comment: The question was in regard to when ini settings does not work due to permissions.

Answer (score 0):

And an even shorter solution:

```
// Rebuild GET variables
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_GET);
```