# PHP $_POST missing field when too much data

Tags: php, ajax, forms, post

I'm using `jQuery.post`, one of the fields is a large string. it's probably 2MB of text.

The `jQuery.post` request goes through okay, but this field doesn't exist in PHP's `$_POST` array.
All other posted fields are fine. It's definitely being sent, and is actually in `file_get_contents("php://input")`

If I reduce the size of the large string, it appears in the `$_POST` data again.

How can I remove this field size limit so PHP will push the large field into `$_POST`?

**EDIT**: I changed `post_max_size` to `100M` and it didn't change anything.

Comment: That is ~1048576 characters! (2 byte chars). This sounds like a server setting issue. Is your post value on the end?

Comment: The default `post_max_size` is 8MB, so it might not be related to PHP's configuration...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try 
[Increasing the maximum post size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135427/increasing-the-maximum-post-size)
Or check if server haven`t got any additional restricion mechanism like 
http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/

check your phpinfo() and look for any post related limits

Comment: I think you're right with that `suhosin` thing. I have `suhosin.post.max_value_length 1000000` which is less than 1MB. I'm having trouble changing it via htaccess though.

Comment: From what i remember with my "experience" with `suhosin` this vars can`t be overwritten from `.htaccess`. Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718609/how-to-override-suhosin-max-value

Comment: Lol, that's a hack and very bad for performance. I can't believe that answer is accepted... I found out there's a `suhosin.ini`, I changed that and it's all good.

Comment: I did not say that it`s a perfect solution and you did not say that you have access to configuration files.

Comment: It seems Suhosin was enforcing a limit on the number of form elements (or POST variables) that could be submitted in a single form. See http://mou.me.uk/2012/08/20/php-max_input_vars-form-element-limits-and-the-suhosin-patch/ and http://diywpblog.com/how-to-increase-max-input-vars/

Answer (score 2):

It's a server configuration. If you're working with PHP under Linux or similiar, you can control these using .htaccess, like so:

```
#set max post size
php_value post_max_size 20M
```

From [What is the size limit of a post request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364840/what-is-the-size-limit-of-a-post-request)

Answer (score 0):

For the record, There are also other options which might cause missing post data,
One would be `max_input_vars` which defines the number of post variables allowed in a request. It is set to a very high value (1000) by default but in some cases you might wanna increase the number.

Also there is `max_input_nesting_level` which could also be the cause incase you have many nested variables (this one is by default 64)